# encrypting and decrypting password in a database

Tags: database, encryption, https, passwords, cloud

So currently at my job I am developing a tech portal that connects to a database to make changes to the database. A server is also connected to the database and periodically checks if new fields have been made in the database, telling an end host if this is true.

My problem is, my boss wants the web app to connect directly to the database and have the server check periodically for changes but this means storing the password with a decryptable encryption method.

What I think the better plan is, is that we connect everything to the server, where the server can then use a one-way encryption method (hashing) to store the password and then also let the end host know the password through a secure https connection (I know this probably still isn't great).

I want to know you're thoughts on this and what you think is the best way to approach this problem. Cheers.

Comment: You're problem description isn't super clear, but connecting a front-end application to a database directly is a very poor idea.  Additionally, encrypting passwords versus hashing them is, again, a very poor idea.

Comment: Sorry about the not great description, but you understood and your answer supports my claims in the project so I can consult my boss about it. Cheers.

Comment: `boss wants the web app to connect directly to the database` you really mean storing database credentials in the web frontend? That's indeed a very bad idea (nothing prevents leaking the credentials). For the backend - you need to store the credentials somewhere anyway, encrypted or not, there is no way around (maybe except using Kerberos with MSSQL).